# Uniform integrability of $X_n=\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $\Omega=(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $((0,1), \mathcal{B}(0,1), \mathcal{Leb}_{(0,1)})$ be a probability space. Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n=\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}$, $n \geq 1$, $\alpha \in(0,1)$.

Is $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ uniformly integrable?

**My attempt**

We need to show that $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq{L^1}$ and that $k(b)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\mathbb{I}_{\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\gt{b}} \underset{b \rightarrow \infty}{{\longrightarrow}}0$.

$\mathbb{E}\big |\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\big |=\big(\frac\alpha2\big)^n \lt\infty\  \forall \ n\geq1$, so $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq{L^1}$. Then (and this is where I am most uncertain)

$\mathbb{E}\ \alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\mathbb{I}_{\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\gt{b}} =  \begin{cases}
\big(\frac\alpha2\big)^n, \ \ \ \ \alpha^n \gt b \\
0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ , \ \ \ \ \alpha^n \leq b
\end{cases}
$

which is decreasing in $n$, so it should be

$k(b)=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}\ \alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\mathbb{I}_{\alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\gt{b}}=\frac\alpha2\mathbb{I}_{(0,\alpha)}(b) \underset{b \rightarrow \infty}{{\longrightarrow}}0$.

I am not sure what I did is correct. Can anyone confirm or correct this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Recall that $(X_n)$ is uniformly integrable if there exists $p>1$ such that $\sup_n\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n\rvert^p]<\infty$.

Comment: $ 0 \leq X_n \leq 1$ and this implies uniform integrability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform integrability follows directly from
$$
\lvert X_n\rvert= \alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}\leqslant \alpha^n\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}\leqslant \mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}.
$$